# R - maximum values

Tags: r

Hey Ive just started learning R. I wanted to ask how i can find the maximum value in a vector based for combination of 2 vectors in a dataframe.
For instance, I want to find the five maximum avg price .
I have a data frame with about 7 columns, 3 of them being average price, city and year. The year is obviously recurrent and ranges from 2000 to 2009. The data also has various NA's in different columns and rows.

```
The Data Frame looks something like this:
avgprice    year    city
12          2000    Jersey City
45          2001    Hoboken   
NA          2000    Hoboken
34          2000    evanston
67          2001    abilene
89          2001    elizabeth
45          2000    delhi       
98          2000    delhi

I want the answer to look like
year    city           avgprice
2000    jersey city     12
2000    evanston        34
2000    delhi           98
2001    hoboken         45
2001    elizabeth       89
2001    abilene         67
```

I tried with the following code but I think I'm messing up something. I tried to create df using split by year and then used an aggregate function.

```
df<-split(tx.house.sales, tx.house.sales$year)
re<-aggregate(avgprice~city, df, FUN=max)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Try `aggregate(avgprice ~ city + year, tx.house.sales, function(x) x[which.max(x)])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some simple options (assuming `df` is the *original* data (not splitted)). The reason that `aggregate` works smoothly is because it has `na.action = na.omit` as default, which suites your exact needs.

```
aggregate(avgprice ~ city + year, df, max)
#          city year avgprice
# 1       delhi 2000       98
# 2    evanston 2000       34
# 3 Jersey City 2000       12
# 4     abilene 2001       67
# 5   elizabeth 2001       89
# 6     Hoboken 2001       45
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(na.omit(df))[, .(avgprice = max(avgprice)), keyby = .(year, city)]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
na.omit(df) %>%
  group_by(city, year) %>%
  summarise(avgprice = max(avgprice))
```

Comment: thank you so much.. Also can you suggest what could be wrong in the following code:
        library(dplyr)
    
        df %>% group_by(city,year) %>% do(.[which.max(.$avgprice),])

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(city,year) %>% slice(which.max(avgprice))

#  avgprice year       city
#1       67 2001    abilene
#2       98 2000      delhi
#3       89 2001  elizabeth
#4       34 2000   evanston
#5       45 2001    Hoboken
#6       12 2000 JerseyCity
```

Updated following @docendo discimus's advice

Comment: You could use `df %>% group_by(city,year) %>% slice(which.max(avgprice))` for better performance